# Problem with SendKeys for Running Accessibility Checker on Initial Document_Open

Tags: vba, ms-word

On a button click I am trying to open an existing document, and upon the documents open, use send keys to simulate going to Review > Check Accessibility. I suspect that it is possibly something with the syntax for sendkeys, as trying the Document_Open alone within a document will not work (possibly need a window selection first?), or the fact that it cannot call the Document_Open after the Shell opens file explorer and a file is selected (again is a window selection needed for the new word document?).

Any help is appreciated!

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim Foldername As String
    Foldername = "\\server\Instructions\"
    Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & Foldername & "", vbNormalFocus
    Call Document_Open
End Sub
Private Sub Document_Open()
    SendKeys "%RA1"
End Sub
```